# Loop list from an input file to do diff

Tags: bash

How can I write a bash script (to do diff) that takes a file as an input that has a list of filenames that need to be compared in a 1:1 way only.
The contents of the input file look like the following:

```
file1.a file1.b
file2.a file2.b
file3.a file3.b
file(n).a file(n).b
```

so the diff should be executed only like the following loop:

```
diff file1.a file1.b
diff file2.a file2.b
diff file3.a file3.b
```

I will be using positional parameters to input the file and will use `awk` and `sed` to get the appropriate name. But I'm not sure how to make it a loop until the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one line using xargs, like this (with `difflist.txt` as your inputfile):

```
xargs -n2 diff < difflist.txt
```

`xargs` builds a commandline, taking arguments (here exactly 2 due to `-n2`)  from the pipe and execute diff with them.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r f1 f2; do
  diff "$f1" "$f2"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything bash-specific in your answer.